# xcode 6 simulator doesn't show home button

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

Today I downloaded final version of Xcode 6. When I run program in Simulator - Simulator doesn't have "Home" button, it shows frameless. I XCode 5 everything was OK.

I didn't find any options to turn it on. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try Apple + H?

Comment: Apple removed the button from the simulator in Xcode 6. You can still access the menu option at `Hardware -> Home` or use the key combination `Command+Shift+H`. I assure you, you're not the only person who hates this change.